# procedure to convert the dates in ms access(vb code requir

Tags: ms-access-2010

i have four forms namely file status , load file, reconciliation, and reports.

Reconciliation form has 2list boxes.. namely fiscal year and fiscal month. In that we have to choose for eg say i chose fiscal year 2012 and month as 1, then when i click open the reports form i have reports in there which displays information as per the year and the month.

what my requirement is in this report it displays fiscal year as i have chosen in the first step. But i do not want it because fiscal year 2012 and fiscal month 1 actually corresponds to actual year 2011 and month 10 i . e October. i want this to be displayed over there.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** the corresponding Calendar Month/Year is always the same period behind, then a simple calculation could be done:

Format(DateAdd("M",-3,Format([FiscalPeriod]&"-01","ddddd")),"MMMM YYYY") 
-OR-
Format(DateAdd("M",-3,Format([FiscalYear]&"-"&[FiscalMonth]&"-01","ddddd")),"MMMM YYYY")

If it's not, then You'll need a lookup table for each Fiscal Period and it's related calendar Month.  Then have that value looked up on Your form using Dlookup() and have the report reference the lookup field instead of the List Boxes.

From the Access Help files:

DLookup(expr, domain [, criteria] )
Sample:
=DLookup("[ProductName]", "Products", "[ProductID] =" & Forms![Order Details]!ProductID)

Comment: thank you for taking your time out to help me, i forgot to mention i got it done already. thanks a lot